# Energy level splitting in a semiconductor

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, semiconductor-physics, pauli-exclusion-principle

[image: semiconductor energy level graph]

In the above image, I see that the graph curves upwards in a weird manner from 
$b$ to $0$. ( middle graph)

I understand the reason that the graph splits from a single energy line to a ‘band’ of energy line due to the exclusion principle. But my professor hasn’t explained why the graph curves in that particular way. 
So if someone could explain why the graph curves that way and also the significance of the particular way it curves I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: That graph is, at best, supposed to help you understand how atomic orbitals become energy bands in solids. As you have found out, it isn't always helpful to all people. But, it is not particularly physical in the first place, so no real harm done.

Comment: Comment. Could you tell me what book cointain that graph of semiconductor band structure? In response to one comment:
this text should be helpfull for understanding band structure:
[link](https://books.google.pl/books?id=lTUNWOR_cDgC&pg=PA843&lpg=PA843&dq=Energy+level+splitting+and+band+formation+in+crystals+of+group+IV+A+elements&source=bl&ots=fBkc7U-jvE&sig=V6iTaNs3TCsXkiSSA9aCPNF4cQk&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_kcTOp_nZAhWOLlAKHVVOCEgQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=Energy%20level%20splitting%20and%20band%20formation%20in%20crystals%20of%20group%20IV%20A%20elements&f=false)!

Comment: My friend and I were discussing this. I don’t remember which book. But Wikipedia has an almost similar diagram.   https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_band_structure it is in the why band and band gaps occur section

Comment: @physics2000 - I suspect that this graph is from the book: C.T. Sah, Fundamentals of Solid State Electronics. It is probably also explained there pretty well. Unfortunately I don't have this book at hand. If you have this book, you could look it up for confirmation.

Comment: @freecharly hmm. Not heard of it.

Comment: @physics2000 - Here is the link: 

https://www.amazon.com/Fundamentals-Solid-State-Electronics-Chih-Tang-Sah/dp/9810206380/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1522082305&sr=1-1&keywords=fundamentals+of+solid+state+electronics
I posses the book but have no access where I am now. It is pretty comprehensive and the author is one of the pioneers of microelectronics.

Answer (score 1):

This diagram demonstrates the creation of energy bands (conduction band and valence band, and the band gap in between) when group IV N atoms (here Si) are brought closer and closer together to form the natural crystal with lattice constant $a_0$ (and beyond).

Each free atoms has 4 electrons in its outer shell (here n=3) which are distributed over the 8 discrete energy states consisting of the 2 s-states (angular momentum l=0, spin up, spin down down) and the 6 p states (angular momentum l=-1, 0, +1, spin up, down). The number of energy levels are always only half as many as the number of states due to the assumed spin degeneracy.

Essential for the understanding of the band structure in this picture is, that the coupling of N atoms always multiplies the number of states of the single atom by N. This is similar to the splitting of eigenfrequencies in N identical coupled oscillators. Thus you have always 8N states over which the 4N electrons will be distributed according to the Pauli principle.

When reducing the distance, the 8N atomic levels first broaden, then overlap and then separate energetically again producing the band gap. At the natural lattice distance, the lowest 4N states of the valence band are fully occupied by the 4N available electrons. Thus the valence band is completely full at absolute zero which is assumed here. And the 4N states of the conduction band is completely empty.

Due to the huge number N of atoms in a semiconductor crystal lattice, the energetic spacings of the energy states are, of course extremely small. This gives you a very nice intuitive understanding of the origin of the semiconductor energy band structure.